# Getting relative mouse X/Y in javascript

Tags: javascript, mouse, coordinates

I have a div somewhere on the page.  I then get the mouse XY:

```
        var relativeMouseX = self.gCurrentMouseX - self.gContainerLeft;
        var relativeMouseY = self.gCurrentMouseY - self.gContainerTop;
```

Where the current mousex/y are obtained via:

```
// Update mouse coords
this.gUpdateMousePos = function(evt) {
    if (evt === undefined) evt = window.event;
    if (window.event) {
        this.gCurrentMouseX = event.clientX;
        this.gCurrentMouseY = event.clientY;
    }
    else {
        this.gCurrentMouseX = evt.clientX;
        this.gCurrentMouseY = evt.clientY;
    }
}
```

This worked fine in testing, but when the div is located down a page, it messes up themouse X/Y, as the co-ordinates only seem to be in the viewinwg area and not the entire page.

X co-ord works fine, because the pages never expand horizontally wider than the browser size, but vertical is a problem!

Any ideas how to get mouse X/Y relative to the element?

Comment: probably you'll just need to know the position of the element and math those differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft` and `event.clientX+document.body.scrollTop`
**or**
`event.pageX` and `event.pageY`

The first one is just adding current scroll position to the value, the second one is the mouse position relative to the page, not the client window.

Comment: however, this is relative to the page, not an element

Comment: Perfect thank you!  Used the scrollTop fix and it works perfectly.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE, document.documentElement.scrollTop works over a wider range of doctypes.

Comment: you can use `pageX` and `pageY` in IE

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the parent elements to find a child element's true position on the page. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

```
 /**
 * Locate the real position of an element,
 * relative to its parent's offsets
 */
function findPos (obj) {
    var curleft = 0,
        curtop = 0;

    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
}
```